# Cant get a secure websocket connection to gdax working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, gdax-api

I'm trying to connect to GDAX websocket feed from C# (Target Framework: Core 2.0)

[I'm using this NodeJS implementation as a reference.](https://github.com/coinbase/gdax-node/blob/master/lib/clients/websocket.js)

My code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws-feed.gdax.com");
ws.Security.AllowUnstrustedCertificate = true; // doesn't matter if I remove this line
ws.Send(json);
ws.MessageReceived += (sender, args) => _log.LogInformation(args.Message);
```

Where json ([Reference](https://docs.gdax.com/#subscribe)):

```
{
  "type": "subscribe",
  "product_ids": [
    "BTC-EUR"
  ],
  "channels": [
    "ticker"
  ]
}
```

I don't see any errors in the log and I tried different libraries for WebSocket. I'm fine with solutions that use other libraries.

Comment: so if you don't have error, what is the issue ?

Comment: the issue is that nothing is received back. Anyway, I figured out the issue, I need to send only after the connection has been opened. "Open" is not synchronous. I'm posing the answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var ws = new WebSocket4Net.WebSocket(url);
        ws.Open();


        ws.DataReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
        ws.MessageReceived += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(args.Message);
        ws.Opened += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("opened: " + args);
            ws.Send(json);
        };
        ws.Error += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("error: " + args);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The problem was that I was sending straight away after calling Open. I should wait and send on the Opened event.